# Aws lambda function api gateway file upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function to upload file

The first step is I am facing to get the files uploaded in python.. After searching I found the *requests_toolbelt.multipart* to try.. but not getting the files or content

I have below code

```
content_type_header = event['headers']['content-type']
    body = event["body"].encode()
    response = ''
    for part in decoder.MultipartDecoder(body, content_type_header).parts:
      response += part.text + "\n"

     return {
         'statusCode': 200,
         'body': response
     }
```

Any help Highly appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: It is commonly a bad idea the upload the file direclty to the lambda function, indeed the payload is quite limited (6 MB) check out AWS doc :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

Comment: Here is the common usage to upload file using the lambda function only to get a signed URL to then POST into S3: https://serverlessland.com/blog/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application--aws-compute-blog